# Add multiple photos to feed using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Tell me please, is it possible to create a feed with multiple photos in facebook timeline using graph API(or some other api?)? I'm writing server side script on PHP.

I need to make a feed post with 3-4 lines of text, link and 3-5 photos in it.

I tried to use albums, but stories created from albums only contained 1 line of text.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I'm looking exactly for the same thing, but have found no correct answer. Do you know, now, how to do that?

Comment: As fas as I recall, this was impossible to do at that moment. The only way to display multiple images in one post was to create an albums and upload them into it. But stories created from albums only can contain 1 line of text. Maybe something changed in the last year, but I just limited image uploads to 1 image per post in my app.

Comment: After many hours, same conclusion. My solution: when I want to put a message only, I use {page-id}/feed, when I want to send only 1 image, I use {page-id}/photos and put the message in the coment field. The photo is inserted automaticly in the TimeLine Album and displayed on the TimeLine with the coment. When I have more than 1 photo, I use {page-id}/album to create one, then {album-id}/photos to put photos inside. I notice also one bug; when you post in {page-id}/feed with parameter "link", it create the link and display image from the website. Same in {group-id}/feed does nothing.